# Uploading image mime-type application/jpg

Tags: image, internet-explorer, file-upload, mime-types, microsoft-edge

We have a few pcs in the office and while testing a websites image uploading in one of them the mime-type detected was "application/jpg" or "application/png" while it should be "image/jpg" and "image/png". The browsers that did this were Internet explorer v11.0 and Edge v40. The versions were same on other pc but the mime-types were ok (image/*). Where is it getting the idea that image mime-type is application/*??

The upload element is nothing special (it is triggered by an outside button):

```
<input style="display:none" id="upload_damage_image" type="file" name="file[0]">
```

Comment: No solution, but someone with the same problem over here: https://superuser.com/questions/942793/internet-explorer-reporting-images-as-application-jpeg-not-image-jpeg

Comment: Yup seen that one, unfortunately they did not solve it, and it is over a year old :(

Comment: do you have other web browsers installed or image editors.that may have changed the file associations.. In Windows 10 you can set the default program by file extension. Other software you have installed may have changed the registry settings. Use Irfanview to open the image files... It will complain if the mime-types do not match the header mime-signature and offer to convert them back to their last saved mime-type.MSIE browsers use mime type sniffing... If the files were originally downloaded from a web site, possibly that web site server is incorrectly configured with the wrong mime type.

Comment: can you post the images with your question please... this will allow us to inspect their mime-signatures.

Comment: You can try (otherwise) setting the accept attribute on the file input element to accept="image/*".... you should notice that the file open dialog is then filtered differently in the test browsers.

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue recently, the cause was Autodesk Pixlr it had overwritten the String value Content Type from "image/jpeg" to "application/jpeg" in registry HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.jpg.

Uninstalled Autodesk Pixlr but it actually deleted the Content Type values rather than restoring to image/*.

Used Regshot to compare registry before and after installation of Autodesk Pixlr. Identified the changed entries below:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.bmp\Content Type: "application/bmp"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.gif\Content Type: "application/gif"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.jpeg\Content Type: "application/jpeg"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.jpg\Content Type: "application/jpg"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.png\Content Type: "application/png"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.tif\Content Type: "application/tif"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.tiff\Content Type: "application/tiff"

So uninstalled it again, backed up registry and created the correct entries below:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.bmp\Content Type: "image/bmp"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.gif\Content Type: "image/gif"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.jpeg\Content Type: "image/jpeg"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.jpg\Content Type: "image/jpeg"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.png\Content Type: "image/png"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.tif\Content Type: "image/tiff"
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes.tiff\Content Type: "image/tiff"

This resolved the issue.